# How to check the pages that are set to allowed in controller CakePhp 3?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1

I have a logout function I am trying to create that will check if the current page is allowed for logged out users. If so I will stay on page, if not I will redirect to the home page. I was wondering how to check if the current page is allowed. I can check if they are authorized with this code:

```
public function logout()
{
    if($this->isAuthorized($this->Auth->user())) {
        $this->Auth->logout();
        $redirect = $this->redirect($this->referer());
    } else {
        $this->Auth->logout();
        $redirect = $this->redirect(['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home']);
    }
    return $redirect;
}
```

but I cannot check if current page is allowed:

```
public function logout()
{
    if(in_array($this->request->here, $this->Auth->allow())) {
        $this->Auth->logout();
        $redirect = $this->redirect($this->referer());
    } else {
        $this->Auth->logout();
        $redirect = $this->redirect(['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home']);
    }
    return $redirect;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to use the `$this->Auth->allowedActions`, whereas Auth component store the allowed actions in the [`allowedAction`](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/source-class-Cake.Controller.Component.AuthComponent.html#189-195) property.
You can call them as the following:

```
$actions = $this->Auth->allowedActions;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an answer, but if there is a better way to do it I would still like to know. I pass the action in a hidden input to the controller method and check if in allowedPages array.

```
public $allowedPages = [];
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->allowedPages = ['checkout', 'charge', 'logout'];
    $this->Auth->allow($this->allowedPages);
}

public function logout()
{
    if(in_array($this->request->data('action'), $this->allowedPages)) {
        $this->Auth->logout();
        $redirect = $this->redirect($this->referer());
    } else {
        $this->Auth->logout();
        $redirect = $this->redirect(['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home']);
    }
    return $redirect;
}
```